# Data not getting inserted into the database table and the page is also not loading to show the response

Tags: java, forms, servlets

I am creating a simple form which accepts student data for admission and then on pressing submit button the data is sent to "addStdInfoServlet" which is a servlet that accepts the data and inserts into database table students using JDBC.

I have written the following code but whenever I submit the form after entering all the info. I servlet page does not load or does not show anything in response and the data also is not getting inserted into the table students.

Please help me with this problem?

**std_registration.html**

```
<form  action="addStdInfoServlet" method="POST"> 
 <input type="text" name="form_no" placeholder="Form No.">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Course Code" name="ccode">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Roll No." name="rollno">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Course Name" name="cname"><br>
  Course commencing from : <input type="date" name="start_from"> To <input type="date" name="till"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Student Surname" name="s_sname">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Student Firstname" name="s_fname">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Student Middlename" name="s_mname"><br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Blood Group" name="bgrp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Aadhar Card No." name="a_id">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Religion" name="religion">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="emailid"><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Father's Surname" name="f_sname">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Father's Firstname" name="f_fname">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Father's Middlename" name="f_mname">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Occupation Of Father" name="occupation"><br>
      <textarea rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Residential Address" name="address"></textarea><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Income Per Annum" name="income">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Contact No." name="contact_no"><br>
      Date Of Birth : <input type="date" name="dob"><br>
      Select Gender:<br><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female <br>
      Select Category : <br>
      <input type="radio" name="cat" value="SC">SC
      <input type="radio" name="cat" value="ST">ST
      <input type="radio" name="cat" value="NT">NT
      <input type="radio" name="cat" value="Others">Others<br><br>


      Educational Qualifications :<br><br>

     <table border="1">
        <tr><th>Examination</th><th>Board/University</th><th>% of Marks</th><th>Year of Passing</th></tr>
        <tr><td>10th std</td><td><input type="text" name="sscboard"></td><td><input type="text" name="sscper"></td><td>
                      <select name="ssc_year">
                      <option value="Select">Select</option> 
                      <option value="2002">2002</option>
                      <option value="2003">2003</option>
                      <option value="2004">2004</option>
                      <option value="2005">2005</option>
                      <option value="2006">2006</option>
                      <option value="2007">2007</option>
                      <option value="2008">2008</option>
                      <option value="2009">2009</option>
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2011">2011</option>
                      <option value="2012">2012</option>
                      <option value="2013">2013</option>
                      <option value="2014">2014</option>
                      <option value="2015">2015</option>
                      <option value="2016">2016</option>
                      </select></td></tr>

        <tr><td>12th std</td><td><input type="text" name="hscboard"></td><td><input type="text" name="hscper"></td>
                    <td><select name="hsc_year">
                     <option value="Select">Select</option> 
                      <option value="2002">2002</option>
                      <option value="2003">2003</option>
                      <option value="2004">2004</option>
                      <option value="2005">2005</option>
                      <option value="2006">2006</option>
                      <option value="2007">2007</option>
                      <option value="2008">2008</option>
                      <option value="2009">2009</option>
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2011">2011</option>
                      <option value="2012">2012</option>
                      <option value="2013">2013</option>
                      <option value="2014">2014</option>
                      <option value="2015">2015</option>
                      <option value="2016">2016</option>
                      </select></td></tr></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Degree/Diploma</td><td><input type="text" name="dboard"></td><td><input type="text" name="dper"></td><td>
                    <select name="d_year">
                      <option value="Select">Select</option> 
                      <option value="2002">2002</option>
                      <option value="2003">2003</option>
                      <option value="2004">2004</option>
                      <option value="2005">2005</option>
                      <option value="2006">2006</option>
                      <option value="2007">2007</option>
                      <option value="2008">2008</option>
                      <option value="2009">2009</option>
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2011">2011</option>
                      <option value="2012">2012</option>
                      <option value="2013">2013</option>
                      <option value="2014">2014</option>
                      <option value="2015">2015</option>
                      <option value="2016">2016</option>
                      </select></td></tr></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Other Courses</td><td><input type="text" name="otherboard"></td><td><input type="text" name="oper"></td><td><select name="o_year">
                      <option value="Select">Select</option> 
                      <option value="2002">2002</option>
                      <option value="2003">2003</option>
                      <option value="2004">2004</option>
                      <option value="2005">2005</option>
                      <option value="2006">2006</option>
                      <option value="2007">2007</option>
                      <option value="2008">2008</option>
                      <option value="2009">2009</option>
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2011">2011</option>
                      <option value="2012">2012</option>
                      <option value="2013">2013</option>
                      <option value="2014">2014</option>
                      <option value="2015">2015</option>
                      <option value="2016">2016</option>
                      </select></td></tr>
    </table>


      Experience : <select name="exp"> 
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option></select> yrs.
                        <br>
                        <br>


    Registration Fee: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="reg_fee" value="cash" > Cash
    <input type="radio" name="reg_fee" value="dd" > DD <br>


    <div class="declaration">
        <p>Declaration</p>
        <p>I hereby solemnly declare that the information furnished by me in this application is true to the best of my knowledge and belief. I abide the rules & regulation. General information  given the prospectus and enforced by the institute from time .If any information found incorrect at any stage of my study. The institute reserves its right to cancel my registration/admission and no fees shall be refunded to me.</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Place" name="place">
        <input type="date" name="admission_date">
        Signature of the applicant:
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**addStdInfoServlet.java**

```
  import java.sql.*;
  import javax.servlet.*;
  import javax.servlet.http.*;
  import java.io.*;





  public class addStdInfoServlet extends HttpServlet
 {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse    response) throws ServletException,IOException
  {
       response.setContentType("text/html");


       int fno = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("form_no"));
       String ccode = request.getParameter("ccode");
       int rno = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rollno"));
       String cname = request.getParameter("cname");
       String start_from = request.getParameter("start_from");
       String till = request.getParameter("till");
       String s_sname = request.getParameter("s_sname");
       String s_fname = request.getParameter("s_fname");
       String s_mname = request.getParameter("s_mname");
       String bgrp = request.getParameter("bgrp");
       int a_id= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a_id"));
       String religion = request.getParameter("religion");
       String emailid = request.getParameter("emailid");
       String f_sname = request.getParameter("f_sname");
       String f_fname = request.getParameter("f_fname");
       String f_mname = request.getParameter("f_mname");
       String occupation = request.getParameter("occupation");
       String address = request.getParameter("address");
       double income = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("income"));
       int contact_no = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contact_no"));
       String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
       String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
       String cat = request.getParameter("cat");
       String sscboard = request.getParameter("sscboard");
       Double sscper = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("sscper"));
       int ssc_year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ssc_year"));
       String hscboard = request.getParameter("hscboard");
       Double hscper = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("hscper"));
       int hsc_year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hsc_year"));
       String dboard = request.getParameter("dboard");
       Double dper = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("dper"));
       int d_year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("d_year"));
       String otherboard = request.getParameter("otherboard");
       Double oper = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("oper"));
       int o_year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("o_year"));
       int exp = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("exp"));
       String reg_fee = request.getParameter("reg_fee");
       String place = request.getParameter("place");
       String admission_date = request.getParameter("admission_date");




      try
   {                         


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/idemi?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root",""); 
       String query = "insert into students values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
       st.clearParameters();
       st.setInt(1,fno);
       st.setString(2,ccode);
       st.setInt(3,rno);
       st.setString(4,cname);
       st.setString(5,start_from);
       st.setString(6,till);
       st.setString(7,s_sname);
       st.setString(8,s_fname);
       st.setString(9,s_mname);
       st.setString(10,bgrp);
       st.setInt(11,a_id);
       st.setString(12,religion);
       st.setString(13,emailid);
       st.setString(14,f_sname);
       st.setString(15,f_fname);
       st.setString(16,f_mname);
       st.setString(17,occupation);
       st.setString(18,address);
       st.setDouble(19,income);
       st.setInt(20,contact_no);
       st.setString(21,dob);
       st.setString(22,gender);
       st.setString(23,cat);
       st.setString(24,sscboard);
       st.setDouble(25,sscper);
       st.setInt(26,ssc_year);
       st.setString(27,hscboard);
       st.setDouble(28,hscper);
       st.setInt(29,hsc_year);
       st.setString(30,dboard);
       st.setDouble(31,dper);
       st.setInt(32,d_year);
       st.setString(33,otherboard);
       st.setDouble(34,oper);
       st.setInt(35,o_year);
       st.setInt(36,exp);
       st.setString(37,reg_fee);
       st.setString(38,place);
       st.setString(39,admission_date);

       st.executeUpdate();
       st.close();
       conn.close();


        out.println(" <!doctype html>"              
           +"<html>"
          +"<head>"
          +"<title>Admin Registration</title>"
          +"<script src=\"js/jquery.min.js\"></script>"
          +"<script src=\"js/script.js\"></script>"
          +"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style/receipt.css\">"
          +"<link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"images/favicon.ico\"  type=\"image/x-icon\">"
          +"<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"images/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">"
         +"</head>"
         +"<body>"

         +"<div class=\"container\">"
         +"<div class=\"container-inner\">"

         +"<div class=\"header\">"  

         +"<div class=\"header-inner1\">"
         +"<div class=\"header-pic\">"
         +"<img src=\"images/logo.png\">"
         +"</div>"
         +"<div class=\"header-text\">"
         +"<p>ONLINE ADMISSION SYSTEM</p>"
         +"</div>"
         +"</div>"

        +"<div class=\"header-inner2\"> "

        +"<div class=\"header-menu\"> "
        +"<ul class=\"menu-tab-grp\">"
        +"<li><a href=\"index.html\">Home</a></li>"
        +"<li><a href=\"about_us.html\">About Us</a></li>"  
        +"<li><a href=\"registration.html\">Registration</a></li>"
        +"<li><a href=\"courses_offered.html\">Courses Offered in IT</a></li>"
        +"<li><a href=\"contactus.html\">Contact Us</a></li>"


       +"</ul>"
       +"</div>"
       +"</div>"
       +"</div>"

       +"<div class=\"main-body\">"
       +"<div class='logout'><h4>Student Information added successfully..!</h4></div>"
        +"</div>"


       +"</div>"
       +"</div>"
       +"</body>"
       +"</html> ");





    }  

   catch(SQLException e)
   {
      System.out.println(e);
   } 

   catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
   {
       System.out.println(e);
   }





     }



    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException,IOException
   {
     doGet(request,response);
   }


  }
```

I am using MySQL database and I have created a table named 'students' which has the following structure:

- form_no     <- Primary key, type:Integer Not Null,
- course_code     <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- roll_no     <- type:Integer Not Null,
- course_name    <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- start_from     <- type:date Not Null,
- till     <- type:date Not Null,
- std_surname     <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- std_firstname    <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- std_middlename    <-type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- blood_group     <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- aadharcard_id   <- type:Integer Not Null,
- religion      <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- emailid       <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- f_surname     <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- f_firstname    <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- f_middlename   <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- occupation     <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- address        <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- income         <- type:Double Not Null,
- contact_no     <- type:Integer Not Null,
- dob            <- type:date Not Null,
- gender         <- type:varchar(10) Not Null,
- category       <- type:varchar(20) Not Null,
- ssc_board      <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- ssc_percentage     <- type:Integer Not Null,
- ssc_passing_year      <- type:Integer Not Null,
- hsc_board      <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- hsc_percentage     <- type:double Not Null,
- hsc_passing_year      <- type:Integer Not Null,
- d_board        <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- d_percentage     <- type:double Not Null,
- d_passing_year      <- type:Integer Not Null,
- other_board      <- type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- other_percentage     <- type:double Not Null,
- other_passing_year      <- type:Integer Not Null,
- experience             <- type:Integer Not Null,
- reg_fee               <- type:Integer Not Null,
- place                 <-  type:varchar(40) Not Null,
- admission_date        <- type:date Not Null,

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: show us your error please

Comment: @afzalex  No. I am not getting any error . I just get a blank page when i fill the form and hit submit.

Comment: @Youcef Laidani  I really don't get any error messages. I just get blank page when I fill the form and hit submit button. Even the data entered does not get inserted into the database table

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the sql command: `insert into vales` The right syntax is `insert into valUes`.

Now you can debug this code quite easily: you can print the sql command and try to run in directly in sql developer.

However, I suggest to use `PreparedStatement` and use its `setString`, `setInt`, ... methods to set the parameters because that's safer.

Comment: thank you for your timely help .. I corrected the code but still when I fill the form and submit it the servlet shows me a blank page.

Comment: Can you see errors in the error log? Is the source of the result page blank too?

Comment: @Sanjay Patel  No servlet does not show any error other than a blank white page dispaying nothing..

Comment: @tamas rev yes on hitting submit button the addStdInfoServlet shows a blank page

Comment: have you check your servlet is called or not?

Comment: tamas rev  @Sanjay Patel yes I checked it is getting called . Now I am inserting data using prepared statement using setInt and setString methods but statements are not getting executed and it still shows a blank page . It is not also giving any errors. If I comment the st.execute() or st.executeUpdate() then I can see my web page but that  is without inserting any values in the table

Comment: print e.printStackTrace() also

Answer (score 0):

As tamas rev said you have typo, if you have another error please tell us .

Also you can use a `sql profiler` to see what exactly go to execute in your sql.

And all of your column are `"Not null`" ,so make sure that your query has all fields.

BTW, where is your   `< /form>` ?

and could you debug it ? i mean , you can easily debug it and catch where exception  happen .

Finally you can catch Exception in your try/catch block in order to catch it and print it .

Answer (score 0):

just try to insert only 2 or 3 field . i have tested your same code , it works for me (insert only first two field).